# Bivariate Normal Distribution properties questions

Tags: probability

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$we have that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with a bivariate normal density with parameters $(μ_x,μ_y, σ^2_x, σ^2_y, ρ_{xy})$. 
And we have to what sentences are true or false.

1) Any linear combination other than $0$ between $X$ and $Y$ with the form $ax+by+c$ has a normal density with mean $aσμ_x+bμy+c$ and a variance of $a^2σ^2_x+b^2σ^2_y$

I got that this one is false because the variance is $a^2σ^2_x+b^2σ^2_y+2ab\Cov(x,y)$

2)If $X$ and $Y$ have the same variance $σ^2$, then $\Var(X+Y)<2σ^2$ if and only if $ρ_{XY}<0$

I got that this is true because $\Var(X+Y)=2σ^2+2\Cov(X,Y)<2σ^2$

3)$\Var(Y\mid X=x) < \Var(y)$

I got that this one is true because
$$
\Var[X_2\mid X_1=x_1] = \sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2).
$$

4) $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $\Cov(X,Y)=0$

I got that this is one is false because $\Cov(X,Y)$ can be $0$ but $X$ and $Y$ not independent. But if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then  $\Cov(X,Y)=0$.

5) $X-Y$ have a normal density if an only if $ ρ_{XY}>0$

I got that this one is false because any lineal combination have a normal distribution too.

The answers are:

a)only 2),3) and 4) are true

b)Only 1) is true

c)only 5) is false

d)All are true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4) is not true in general but in the case of a bivariate normal is true. When  $cov(X,Y)=0$, the covariance matrix   $\Sigma$ becomes  a diagonal matrix. Therefore the bivariate density is a product of two univariate normals  $N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_x)$ , $N(\mu_y,\sigma^2_y)$. Thus we have independence.